# Defining the email address for the Mail::send() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Apologies if I'm missing something here as I'm new to Laravel but when I send a closure to the Mail::send() method to define the mail recipient, it works fine if the email address is available the global scope, like this:

```
Mail::send('frontend.emails.default', $data, function($message) 
{
    $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Hi');
});
```

But how can I pass a value in that's scoped to the calling method? For example:

```
$user = User::find($id);

Mail::send('frontend.emails.default', $data, function($message) 
{
    $message->to($user->email)->subject('Hi');
});
```

I tried adding it to the $data array but that's used in the view and isn't available in the callback.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's a little documented feature in PHP that allows you to pass variables from the current scope into a closure.  In short, you need to `use ($user)`...

```php
$user = User::find($id);

Mail::send('frontend.emails.default', $data, function($message) use ($user)
{
    $message->to($user->email)->subject('Hi');
});
```

Comment: What black magic `use ($var)` is this you speak of?!  ... wow. Thanks for that Phil! A seemingly insignificant feature/answer that just made my day a whole lot easier. I'm going to do some digging around the docs/etc to see what the `use ($var)` actually does behind the scenes. To be honest, I've never used it outside of namespace related `use \Namespace\Class`

Thanks again.

Comment: @ErikTheDeveloper you can find a little information about `use` in the [Anonymous Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) documentation.

Comment: @darronz, Don't know what issue you had, but spaces doesn't matter: http://3v4l.org/6anJp

Comment: @nicholas-ruunu you're right. It's shouldn't have anything to do with the spaces. I've removed my comment as it could be misleading for someone else