# How can I dinamically pass the recipient e-mail address into the Mail::send() inner callback function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-mail

I am pretty new in **PHP** and moreoer in **Laravel** and I am finding some difficult trying to send an e-mail to a not predefine user.

So I am using the **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail** class.

If I do something like this it works fine:

```
$registrationMail = [
    'title' => 'Registrazione albergatore su portale BeTrivius',
    'url' => URL::to('/').'/activate?email='.$data['email'].'&token='.$token,
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'surname' => $data['surname']
];

Mail::send('emails.registrationMail', $registrationMail, function($message) {
    $message->to('mail@gmail.com', 'recipient-name')->subject('email subject');
});
```

So I am calling the **send()** method of the **Mail** class passing to it:

- The **view** representing the e-mail template.
- An array containing some data used into the previous view.
- A callback function in which is contained the  logic to set the recipient e-mail address and the e-mail subject

It works fine but doning in this way the email recipient is static and the e-mail will be send always to the same e-mail address.

This is not good for me because I have to send this e-mail to the address contained into the **$registrationMail['email']** property.

But doing in this way:

```
Mail::send('emails.registrationMail', $registrationMail, function($message) {

    $message->to($registrationMail['email'], $data['name'].' '.$data['surname'])->subject('titolo');
});
```

the **$registrationMail** seems to be not visible into the callback function (it says to me **Undefined variable**). Why I can't see an external property from the inside of a callback function?

So I can't retrieve this information in this way.

So I tryied to add the **$registrationMail** variable as a parameter of this callback function, in this way:

```
Mail::send('emails.registrationMail', $registrationMail, function($message, $registrationMail) {

    $message->to($registrationMail['email'], $registrationMail['name'].' '.$registrationMail['surname'])->subject('titolo');
});
```

Doing in this way the **$registrationMail** variable is not undefined but when it try to send the e-mail I obtain this error message:

```
ErrorException in RegistrationController.php line 90:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}()
in RegistrationController.php line 90
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Missing argument 2 for App\\Http\\Controllers\\RegistrationController::App\\Http\\Controllers\\{closure}()', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\HotelRegistration\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\RegistrationController.php', 90, array('message' => object(Message))) in RegistrationController.php line 90
at RegistrationController->App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(object(Message))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Message)) in Mailer.php line 199
at Mailer->send('emails.registrationMail', array('title' => 'Registrazione albergatore su portale BeTrivius', 'url' => 'http://laravel.dev/activate?email=nobili.andrea@gmail.com&token=4759d4ec56cf1e63447638e0d7a042e6', 'email' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Andrea', 'surname' => 'Nobili'), object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 221
at Facade::__callStatic('send', array('emails.registrationMail', array('title' => 'Registrazione albergatore su portale BeTrivius', 'url' => 'http://laravel.dev/activate?email=nobili.andrea@gmail.com&token=4759d4ec56cf1e63447638e0d7a042e6', 'email' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Andrea', 'surname' => 'Nobili'), object(Closure))) in RegistrationController.php line 93
at Mail::send('emails.registrationMail', array('title' => 'Registrazione albergatore su portale BeTrivius', 'url' => 'http://laravel.dev/activate?email=nobili.andrea@gmail.com&token=4759d4ec56cf1e63447638e0d7a042e6', 'email' => 'nobili.andrea@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Andrea', 'surname' => 'Nobili'), object(Closure)) in RegistrationController.php line 93
at RegistrationController->store(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RegistrationController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
```

where **line 90** is:

```
Mail::send('emails.registrationMail', $registrationMail, function($message, $registrationMail) {
```

So the problem seems to be that I can't pass a second parameter to the inner callback function. Why?

How can I correctly pass the recipient e-mail address into this inner callback function? What is the smartest way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining the email address for the Mail::send() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809254/defining-the-email-address-for-the-mailsend-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the variable to the `use` part of your function to send it to the same scope.

For example:

```
Mail::send('emails.registrationMail', $registrationMail, function($message) use($registrationMail) {
    $message->to($registrationMail['email'])->subject('titolo');
});
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine. What exatly does the use() function? It attach an object\variable to a function content? or what?

Comment: the `function` creates an entirely new closure without any variables.The `use` function allows you to send existing variables into this closure.

Comment: mmm ok...I think that I am understanding but...what exactly represents a "closure"?